# How could I change window's location without reloading and # hack?

Tags: javascript, ajax, facebook, url, history

At first I thought that hash hack is a requirement, however judging from the recent updates from facebook, I am thinking otherwise.

The original hash hack (I am not sure if this is the correct term) is that by changing location.hash, one may save a state in the URL without refreshing the page. That is extensively used by Google's apps, and Facebook, and lately #NewTwitter. However today I noticed that Facebook no longer have this "#" if you use a "modern" browser - like chrome or firefox. I double checked that they are not reloading by using developer tools and firebug respectively.

With a minimal search in stackoverflow, the closest one to the solution is using Flash - however I disabled Flash and facebook.com still works like a charm. 
Judging from the coverage in chrome 8 dev and firefox 4 beta, I wonder that could be related to HTML5-era APIs, but the code in Facebook is not of my capacity to debug to find out what they did.

Since this is like the first question I ask here, I wonder if any of you may have already solved this problem.

Thanks guys.

P.S. Doesn't work on IE8, haven't tested on IE9 beta.

Comment: What "Doesn't work on IE8"? :) This is covered by Google's AJAX crawling guidelines. They have a showcase at http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html which may be useful here.

Comment: I don't know if this is the answer, but there is [client-side data storage](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/) in HTML5. Perhaps that is utilized. In Safari (and I assume Chrome) there's a "Storage" section of the developer tools. Perhaps that will give some hints.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Facebook is using the history api in HTML5. From [this blog post](http://www.spoiledmilk.dk/blog/?p=1922) you can see how this works. Basically they are making calls like the one below to change the url without reloading the page.

```
window.history.pushState("object or string", "Title", "/new-url");
```

Here is the HTML5 working draft spec about it: http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/history.html#the-location-interface

Sadly, IE9 does not support this api. New versions of Chrome and FF have full support.

Comment: Thanks for answering and I think I need to dig deeper in the dev specs. -> http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/history.html

Comment: I just found this jquery plugin you may want to check out. It seems pretty good for handling this, plus it degrades to handle browsers that don't support HTML5. http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/

Comment: What about ie9. How to do it in ie9