# how does Facebook change the url without reloading the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, facebook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How could I change window's location without reloading and # hack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997181/how-could-i-change-windows-location-without-reloading-and-hack)
>   [Facebook and Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5792859/facebook-and-ajax)

How does Facebook change the url without reloading the page?

Earlier facebook used the hash (#) to prevent the page from reloading each time new data had to load, but now a days Facebook change the whole url?! How the **beeep** is that possible?

Comment: Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/136458/how-do-i-with-javascript-change-the-url-in-the-browser-without-loading-the-new

Comment: http://www.spoiledmilk.dk/blog/?p=1922

Answer (score 4):

They're using the [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.history).
You can find [some more demos](https://developer.mozilla.org/demos/search/?q=history%20api) at MDN too.